# Tapping the loading indicator when voting on comment crashes Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, comment-voting

Steps to replicate:

1. Tap a comment
2. Tap "Vote Up"
3. Tap the spinning circle quickly

The spinning circle stops and is highlighted for a split second, then the application reports that it had crashed. It is an IndexOutOfBoundsException (Invalid index 0, size is 0) in `CommentDialog.java`, line 76.

---

- Stack Exchange: *1.0.31*
- Phone/Android: *HTC One, Android 4.4.2*

Comment: A comment for testing purposes.

Comment: Reproduced: app 1.0.31, htc one with Android 4.4.2 just like the asker.

Comment: bros, do you even bounds check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of version 1.0.32 this will be fixed on all modals like this which present a list and sometimes a loading symbol. This means comment upvoting, flagging, and anything else that ends up using this later on.

Thanks for reporting it!

Comment: Verified with 1.0.32. Thank you Kasra!